# Faster prime factorization for huge BigIntegers in Java

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, factorization

so I'm working on a java code right now.  I've gotten it working totally fine, however the point of the assignment is to make it factorize big number (over 30 digits).  It does that, however it can take over 15 minutes for it to do it, which is no good.  My professor assures me that the algorithm I am using will work for numbers up to 2^70 and should do it in about five minutes.  I have been trying to come up with a way to do it (incrementing by 2 instead of 1, etc), but I can't really seem to figure out how to get it to move quicker without skipping some factors.  Any ideas?  I also figured that the Elliptic Curve method would be better, but he told me to not deal with that right now.

Here is my code (ps, the sqrt is my own function but I am sure it is working):

```
public String factorizer(BigInteger monster){
    System.out.println("monster =" + monster); 
    String factors = "";  
    BigInteger top = maths.monsterSqrt(monster);   
    if(monster.mod(two).equals(0));
        BigInteger jump = two;
    for(BigInteger bi = two; bi.compareTo(top) <= 0; bi = bi.add(jump)){
        while(monster.mod(bi).equals(zero)){
            factors +=  "+" + bi + ""; 
            monster = monster.divide(bi); 
            jump = one; 
        }
    }
    if(monster.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) == 1){
        factors  += "+" + monster; 
    } 
    return factors; 
}
```

Comment: This if is useless 

`    if(monster.mod(two).equals(0));`

-> Remove the semicolon 

* If you check for dividability(?) by 2, you should test for 3,5... then

* The for/while nested loop is somewhat incomprehensible, you should rewrite your function in a recursive style.

* I'd accumulate the results in e.g. an ArrayList<BigInteger>, but this is a matter of style :-)

Comment: You can use `Stringbuilder` for factors instead of String. [Class StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Comment: @Gyro it's worse than useless, it invalidates the entire algorithm.

Comment: @Smit true enough, but that's going to be a very minor factor (pun intended) in the overall performance since the #factors will never exceed 70

Comment: @Arend: Sorry i wasn't finished with my comment (fat thumb syndrome)

Comment: @Arend Agreed! Its not going to make very much impact on performance.  OP working on very big number which will definitely take time unless OP uses some other way to improve. @ user2410731 [See here Integer factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization)  **AND**  [Prime Factorization](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFactorization.html)

Comment: Here's another optimization for you: include a hard-coded table of the first hundred or so primes, and use those as test factors at first. Only use your "jump" loop after they've been exhausted. I'm also not convinced that it's ever necessary for "jump" to be one; once you've eliminated all the powers of two from your number, all the remaining factors will be odd numbers. (Someone correct me if I'm wrong.)

Answer (score 6):

Here is my version of integer factorization by trial division:

```
public static LinkedList tdFactors(BigInteger n)
{
    BigInteger two = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
    LinkedList fs = new LinkedList();

    if (n.compareTo(two) < 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("must be greater than one");
    }

    while (n.mod(two).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
    {
        fs.add(two);
        n = n.divide(two);
    }

    if (n.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0)
    {
        BigInteger f = BigInteger.valueOf(3);
        while (f.multiply(f).compareTo(n) <= 0)
        {
            if (n.mod(f).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
            {
                fs.add(f);
                n = n.divide(f);
            }
            else
            {
                f = f.add(two);
            }
        }
        fs.add(n);
    }

    return fs;
}
```

This code is explained in an [essay](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) on my blog, where there is also an explanation of Pollard's rho algorithm, which may be more suitable for factoring big integers.

By the way, 30 digits is not a particularly big factorization problem these days. Anything more than a few seconds is too long.

Comment: Very quick! Really like it!

Comment: I know this is very last, but I must be missing something....I tested your code on 71994651332404115788173195239 using a recent high-end laptop, and it takes like forever.

Comment: As I told you by private email last week, your number factors as 134567897654321 * 535006138814359. Yes, it will take a while. You will need to use elliptic curves or the quadratic sieve to factor that number.

Answer (score 2):

When you divide your `monster` by a prime factor, you should also adjust `top` accordingly. As it is, the outer loop will always run up to the square root of the original number, in increments of 1 or 2, which for a 30-digit number takes in the order of 10^15 steps... it's to be wondered that you are done in only 15 minutes!

If your monster number has very large prime factors (say it is a prime itself), then you can forget about good performance in any case.

Note that your example code does the increments wrong: if the original number is not even then `jump` will always remain `two`, meaning that you only investigate even factors and hence will not find any.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are returning a String!

This works for me. Note that it compares `i` with `n / i` and `n = n / i` each time around:

```
// Memoization of factors.
static Map<BigInteger, List<BigInteger>> factors = new HashMap<>();
private static final BigInteger TWO = BigInteger.ONE.add(BigInteger.ONE);

public static List<BigInteger> factors(BigInteger n, boolean duplicates) {
  // Have we done this one before?
  List<BigInteger> f = factors.get(n);
  if (f == null) {
    // Start empty.
    f = new ArrayList<>();
    // Check for duplicates.
    BigInteger last = BigInteger.ZERO;
    // Limit the range as far as possible.
    for (BigInteger i = TWO; i.compareTo(n.divide(i)) <= 0; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
      // Can have multiple copies of the same factor.
      while (n.mod(i).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        if (duplicates || !i.equals(last)) {
          f.add(i);
          last = i;
        }
        // Remove that factor.
        n = n.divide(i);
      }
    }
    if (n.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0) {
      // Could be a residue.
      if (duplicates || n != last) {
        f.add(n);
      }
    }
    // Memoize.
    factors.put(n, f);
  }
  return f;
}
```